Facebook Canvas Share/Feed dialog not grabbing OG metadata tags while unauthenticated with the `facebookexternalhit` user_agent
What question do I have
Has anyone else noticed facebooks Feed Dialog breaking when trying to generate a share link to apps.facebook.com/game_slug? (Breaking as in there is no thumbnail, description etc since the OG metadata tags cannot be parsed)
Are there any workarounds to maintain the share link as apps.facebook.com/game_slug instead of changing it to be the Facebook Web Games URL: game_slug.domain.com/facebook (the domain that I own)
Facebook has unfortunately closed the ability to submit tickets based on issues with the javascript SDK. However the issue seems to be with how Facebook has stopped allowing crawlers hitting their domain.
Bug Overview
Our Facebook Canvas Web Game's ability to use the FB SDK to share a Feed Post has stopped working. It looks like Facebook cannot crawl our https://apps.facebook.com/game_slug due to the facebookexternalhit user_agent being unauthenticated.
What happens if we try to share a link such as: 
https://apps.facebook.com/game_slug/user/1234
Facebook will automatically redirect the request to: 
https://facebook.com/login
This is all because the user_agent is unauthenticated on Facebook.
Our Web Games URL: 
https://game_slug.domain.com/facebook
Does not get hit before Facebook redirects to a Login Page.
Details and Workaround
I've determine that yes the core problem is that facebooks facebookexternhit user_agent crawler cannot access my OG MetaData tags located at https://game_slug.domain.com/facebook when the user hits the end point as an unauthenticated user.
I ran this curl command to validate the redirect:
curl -v --compressed -H "Range: bytes=0-524288" -H "Connection: close" -A "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)" "https://apps.facebook.com/game_slug/facebook"
* Host apps.facebook.com:443 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 157.240.3.20
*   Trying 157.240.3.20:443...
* Connected to apps.facebook.com (157.240.3.20) port 443
* ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / AEAD-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256 / [blank] / UNDEF
* ALPN: server accepted h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Menlo Park; O=Meta Platforms, Inc.; CN=*.facebook.com
*  start date: Aug 28 00:00:00 2024 GMT
*  expire date: Nov 26 23:59:59 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "apps.facebook.com" matched cert's "*.facebook.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* using HTTP/2
* [HTTP/2] [1] OPENED stream for https://apps.facebook.com/game_slug/facebook
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:method: GET]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:scheme: https]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:authority: apps.facebook.com]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:path: /game_slug/facebook
* [HTTP/2] [1] [user-agent: facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [accept: */*]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [accept-encoding: deflate, gzip]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [range: bytes=0-524288]
> GET /game_slug/facebook HTTP/2
> Host: apps.facebook.com
> User-Agent: facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
> Range: bytes=0-524288
> Connection: close
> 
< HTTP/2 302 
< location: https://apps.facebook.com/login/?next=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fgame_slug%facebook
< reporting-endpoints: coop_report="https://www.facebook.com/browser_reporting/coop/?minimize=0", coep_report="https://www.facebook.com/browser_reporting/coep/?minimize=0"
< report-to: {"max_age":2592000,"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/browser_reporting\/coop\/?minimize=0"}],"group":"coop_report","include_subdomains":true}, {"max_age":86400,"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/browser_reporting\/coep\/?minimize=0"}],"group":"coep_report"}
< cross-origin-embedder-policy-report-only: require-corp;report-to="coep_report"
< cross-origin-opener-policy: same-origin-allow-popups
< origin-agent-cluster: ?1
< strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; preload
< content-type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
< x-fb-debug: pdnC+tC56UXrrEOTFN2H+vqr2Wq7/I+lY4Q/0a3Di4uoX/RiY1/HTib39aM1E2+83X9Dm6wOFje1kxz1edu1Ww==
< content-length: 0
< date: Mon, 18 Nov 2024 20:51:00 GMT
< x-fb-connection-quality: EXCELLENT; q=0.9, rtt=20, rtx=0, c=10, mss=1380, tbw=3395, tp=-1, tpl=-1, uplat=18, ullat=0
< alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400
< 
* Connection #0 to host apps.facebook.com left intact

At no point does this hit my domain to get the metadata.
Everything works find if I use my domain as the share link, allowing the crawler to hit my domain to get the OG metadata, allowing the user to post to their feed.
If another user hits the shared link, then they'll be taken to my domain, and redirected back to apps.facebook.com/game_slug with the proper deeplink/query params.
I've confirmed all my robots.txt is correct, and I'm outputing the metadata tags correctly, the root of the problem is not being able have the facebook crawler start with apps.facebook.com/game_slug
